# NodeJS decode base64 to a PDF

Tags: node.js, base64, nodemailer

I´m trying to decode a Base64 String to a PDF. But the generated File is broken and I cant open it with Adobe Reader. What am I doing wrong?

This is my Code from server Side:

```
let data = req.body;

const base64String = data.pdf;

  const pdfBuffer = Buffer.from(base64String, 'base64');

  fs.writeFile('output.pdf', pdfBuffer,{encoding:"binary"}, err => {
    if(err){
        console.log(err)
    }else{
        console.log("PDF CREATED")
    }
  })
```

This is my Code from Client Side:

```
let pdf;

   const createPDF = () => {

    const report = new JsPDF('portrait','pt','a4');
    report.html(document.querySelector(['.input_container'],[imageURL])).then(() => {
        pdf = report.output('datauristring');
    });

    
  }

const data =  {
      pdf,
}
```

My Goal is when I manage to convert the base64 to PDF, to send this PDF as a Attachment with nodemailer.